# could you explain all the grammar which is included in the sentence: 君子務本，本立而道生?

Tags: grammar

i would like to understand how one could with respect to grammar analyse this phrase, for instance by a syntax tree or naming the unique features of wenyan grammar included in this example.

Answer (score 2):

S: 君子務本

NP: 君子; VP: 務本

N: 君子; V: 務; N:本

S: 本立而道生

NP: 本; VP: 立; CONJ/AP: 而; NP: 道; VP: 生

N: 本; V: 立; and/adverb: 而 (and then); N: 道; V: 生

Alternative:

S: 本立而道生

If: (omit); NP: 本; VP: 立; AP: 而; NP: 道; VP: 生